# AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer in Spring-Security deprecated - is there an alternative?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-websocket

I'm trying to learn more about Spring-Websocket in combination with Spring-Security and was trying out the examples from the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/websocket.html).

After creating my class `WebSecurityConfig` and extending from `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` I was informed that `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` is deprecated.

I tried to find out if there is an alternative to use Spring-Security with Spring-Websocket but couldn't find something on that.

So, my question is should I still use `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` or is there an alternative way to combine Spring-Security with Spring-Websocket?

This is the example I implemented to my test project. It seems to working thine, but shouldn't be there an alternative from Spring before making `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` deprecated?

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

        protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
                messages.simpDestMatchers("/user/*").authenticated();
        }
}
```

Comment: The alternative is in the javadoc. As it always is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Please, read JavaDocs of that deprecated class:

```
 * @deprecated as of 5.0 in favor of simply using {@link WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer}
 * which has default methods, made possible by a Java 8 baseline.
 */
@Deprecated
public abstract class AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
```

Comment: Do you see this in your IDE? In IntelliJ I just have the `/** @deprecated */` comment. But after your answer I looked again in the Spring Docs and really embarrassed that I overlooked the comment under the `Deprecated`.

Comment: Well, I always have source code attached to the project, so when I see a deprecating warning, I jump into source code to determine the reason and alternatives. All thanks to Open Source nature of Spring!

Comment: You can download the source of decompiled classes by using "Download Sources" option in IntelliJ when you open the class. It contains the Javadoc comments.